# Sending a binary file through socket

Tags: c++, sockets, binaryfiles

I'm trying to send a binary file through socket in C to an embedded platform, but when I run it after its sent it just gives me segfault (sending through ftp works fine, but its very slow).
Sending the binary file in same system works ok (the embedded is little-endian so I don't think its endian problem).
What can be the problem? the program is [mft.cpp](http://pastebin.com/sQBDJ1GK)

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that every `read` returns the number of bytes that you want to read. That is incorrect. You should always check the `read` return value to see if you got as many bytes as you wanted.

This also means that you can rewrite your send loop as:

```
int bytesLeft = file_length;
char buf[1024]; //no need to reallocate it in the loop
while(bytesLeft > 0)
{
        int to_read = 1024;
        if(bytesLeft < to_read)
                to_read = bytesLeft 
        int bytesRead = read(new_sock_id, buf, to_read);
        if(error("reading file", false)) continue;
        write(file, buf, bytesRead);
        if(error("writing file", false)) continue;
        bytesLeft -= bytesRead ;
}
```

Comment: I don't need to allocate fixed size buffer

Comment: Correct. I haven't coded C++ for a couple of years. The rest still apply

Comment: And if the socket fills up, write will write a partial buffer and return the number of bytes written.

Comment: This still doesn't work... @mark4o: how do I know if the socket fills up?

Comment: You have to check the return value of `write()`.  If it is less than `bytesRead` then it did not write all of the data.

Comment: @mark4o its equal to bytes read always. I hexdumped both files and it seems to always mess up after 00005d4.